# Stream that inherits class Stream and can be serialized C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, stream

I have an ASP.NET MVC application (I also use jQuery). 
I allow the user to upload a file using `HttpPostedFileBase` class.
Then, I use the `InputStream` property of type `Stream` to save the file stream to some database I have, where I first serislize my object. `Stream` is seralizeable, so no problems here.

The problem begins when the user doesn't upload a file, and I want in this case to use another default file I have somewhere.
In this case, everything has to be similar to the first case, so eventually I'll have a `Stream` in my database. So I have to instance a `Stream` and store it. `Stream` is abstract, so I can't instance `Stream`. Instead I used `FileStream`, which inherits `Stream`. The problem is that `FileStream` is not seralizeable, so here I have a problem.

How can I solve it? Is there another stream I can use which inherits `Stream` and is serializeable?

Answer (score 4):

Don't *serialize* a stream for storage; a stream is a "hose", not a "bucket". Instead, *read* the stream and store the binary data (most databases will have a data-type for binary data, such as `varbinary(max)`). If this is part of an object model, I would be inclined to have a `byte[]` property (with a meaningful name); that will serialize trivially as part of the model. Just read the stream to create a `byte[]`; job done. For example:

```
public static byte[] ReadToEnd(this Stream s) {
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        s.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Maybe you should show an example with using `new SqlBytes(Stream)` - in case he gets a user uploading a 8GB file, or something.

Comment: Perhaps the word "database" is not right for this case. It's not actually a database, only a class I use to store and retrieve data.

Comment: @Jonathan it is a valid concern, but that is a bit of a specialized case - probably worthy of a question by itself.

Comment: @Augustina that doesn't change much, though; most streams will only make sense *briefly* (for example, as part of an HTTP request) - trying to keep them around as objects sounds like a mistake IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358923/stream-that-inherits-class-stream-and-can-be-serialized-c/7358967#7358967) and [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358923/stream-that-inherits-class-stream-and-can-be-serialized-c/7358976#7358976) have good answers. I prefer Marc's as you have the option of having the SQL layer read sequentially from the stream, instead of buffering all the data in memory (which could lead to an `OutOfMemoryException`).

However, at the base level you are approaching this incorrectly. SQL engines, in general, really don't like working with large column values - they are incredibly inefficient at it. There is another 'database' that you can use - your filesystem.

So typically you would define your DB structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files]
(
   [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   [Storage] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
);
```

In the C# land you would first write the file to disk, and use that identifier to update the database:

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes a stream to a file and returns a <see cref="Guid"/> that
/// can be used to retrieve it again.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="incomingFile">The incoming file.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="Guid"/> that should be used to identify the file.</returns>
public static Guid WriteFile(Stream incomingFile)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "MyApplication");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "BinaryData");

    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var ba = guid.ToByteArray();

    // Create the path for the GUID.
    path = Path.Combine(ba[0].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(ba[1].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(ba[2].ToString("x2"));
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path); // Always succeeds, even if the directory already exists.

    path = Path.Combine(guid.ToString() + ".dat");
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[Environment.SystemPageSize];
        var length = 0;
        while ((length = incomingFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    return guid;
}

/// <summary>
/// Deletes a file created by <see cref="WriteFile"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="guid">The original <see cref="Guid"/> that was returned by <see cref="WriteFile"/>.</param>
public static void DeleteFile(Guid guid)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "MyApplication");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "BinaryData");

    var ba = guid.ToByteArray();

    // Create the path for the GUID.
    path = Path.Combine(ba[0].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(ba[1].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(ba[2].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(guid.ToString() + ".dat");
    if (File.Exists(path))
        File.Delete(path);
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads the a file that was created by <see cref="WriteFile"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="guid">The original <see cref="Guid"/> that was returned by <see cref="WriteFile"/>.</param>
/// <returns>The stream that can be used to read the file.</returns>
public static Stream ReadFile(Guid guid)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "MyApplication");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "BinaryData");

    var ba = guid.ToByteArray();

    // Create the path for the GUID.
    path = Path.Combine(ba[0].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(ba[1].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(ba[2].ToString("x2"));
    path = Path.Combine(guid.ToString() + ".dat");
    return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
}
```

You should also investigate [Transactional NTFS](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/11/05/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Introducing-TxF-in-C_2300_-_2800_part-1_2900_-_2D00_-Transacted-file-delete.aspx) to ensure your DB and filesystem stay in sync. The innefficiency of storing BLOB in MsSQL is one of the reasons Microsoft implemented TxF - so you should take their advice - *don't store BLOB/Files in SQL*.

**Side Note:** Having the nested folders (`ba[0 through 2]`) is important for both performance AND file system limitations - a single folder can't hold a really large number of files.

Comment: My DB is actually a class that allow me to store objects and retrieve them. Since I had the `InputStream` property for `HttpPostedFileBase`, I thought I'll store the stream and therefore needed a solution to store data for the other case (file was not uploaded - got my own instead) which will have the same result - `Stream` in my "database".

Comment: @Augustina - you can still store the GUID in the class - this solution works for more than a real SQL DB. Just remember that one day some user is going to upload a multi-gigabyte file to your server and outright crash it.